# Confusing Documentation for Azure AD v2 Sample

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to follow the instructions at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2. Unfortunately, the Azure Portal UI has changed, and appears to be significantly different from what the instructions assume.

For example, step 5 under **Register your app**:

- In the list of pages for the app, select Authentication.
- In the Redirect URIs, add a redirect URL of type Web and valued
  https://localhost:44321/signin-oidc
- In the Advanced settings section set Logout URL to https://localhost:44321/signout-oidc
- In the Advanced settings | Implicit grant section, check ID tokens as this
  sample requires the Implicit grant flow to be enabled to sign-in the 
  user.
- Select Save.

There is no list of pages, no Authentication choice. Nor is there a Redirect URIs section that I could find. There is a Reply URLs section, but it doesn't match the documentation, either.

Does anyone know of an example using AD v2 whose documentation has been kept up to date with the Azure Portal?

Answer (score 1):

The instructions provided in that sample use the preview experience. This experience is currently not available in B2C tenants.

Ensure you are using the preview experience by navigating to `Azure Active Directory` > `App registrations (Preview)` in a non-B2C tenant.

[image: Azure portal navigation]

When you register an application, the left hand navigation will look like this:

[image: App navigation]

When you select `Authentication`, you'll see three sections: Redirect URIs, Advanced settings and Supported account types.

Comment: Thanx, @LesiaNalepa. Replying to your reply on the github issue thread, I'm willing to use a different tenant...provided it lets me use social logins from Google and MicrosoftAccount. But since I'm still learning about tenancy, I'm not even sure where to begin looking to see if that's possible.

Comment: @MarkOlbert if you want to sign-in with google, then for the moment, you need to use Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you want to use Azure AD B2C: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview